# How can I do without join to split one columns into multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

HealthCare :

| A | B | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 582 | X | 1 |
| 582 | Y | 2 |
| 755 | 123 | 1 |
| 755 | 456 | 2 |
| 811 | abc | 1 |
| 811 | def | 2 |

desire result:

| ID | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 582 | X | 755 | 123 | 811 | abc |
| 2 | 582 | Y | 755 | 456 | 811 | def |

or

| ID | 582 | 755 | 811 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | 123 | abc |
| 2 | Y | 456 | def |

I can do like this :

```
SELECT ID, A, B
FROM HealthCare as a
LEFT JOIN (select A as C, B as D from HealthCare where A = 755) as b
    ON a.ID = b.ID
LEFT JOIN (select A as E, B as F from HealthCare where A = 811) as c
    ON a.ID = c.ID 
WHERE A = 582
```

Is any method to do this without joins or with less joins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use `JOIN` I think we can try to use the condition aggregate function to make it, try to add the condition in `CASE WHEN` expression.

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN A = 582 THEN A END) 'A',
       MAX(CASE WHEN A = 582 THEN B END) 'B',
       MAX(CASE WHEN A = 755 THEN A END) 'C',
       MAX(CASE WHEN A = 755 THEN B END) 'D',
       MAX(CASE WHEN A = 582 THEN B END) 'E',
       MAX(CASE WHEN A = 811 THEN B END) 'F'
FROM HealthCare 
GROUP BY ID
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=d9e1892d8b165ee3e9ab37b9576e41f0)